# Why is the audio volume level at 0 every time I start my Mac?

Tags: mac, audio, startup, sound-volume

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature in Mac OS X 10.7. Every time I (re)start my Mac the volume of my audio device is set to zero and doesn't remember the last level I set.

I think this started some weeks ago, maybe with a Lion update. I don't remember changing any audio-related setting.

Is this something I can change? I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.2 on a 2009 MacBook Pro which sometimes I connect to a 24" Cinema display (but it seems that the behavior doesn't depend whether it's using the laptop's or the display's speakers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer on AskDifferent's sister site Superuser.com:

[Snow Leopard resets sound volume whenever I start my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/36572/snow-leopard-resets-sound-volume-whenever-i-start-my-computer)

> In Macintosh HD / Library / Preferences / Audio there are two audio setting files. Delete them. Set your sound to the desired setting. Restart.

This solved my issue.

[image: Audio settings Mac]

Comment: Which files? I only found one file in Username - Library, and there's no Audio folder in Macintosh HD - Library - Preferences.

Comment: @user54825 I added a screenshot that shows the the two files and the folder path.